# Betrayed, Is it reasonable for my character to hold a grudge?

Tags: dnd-5e, betrayal

I'm still very new to D & D but I've been improving and have gotten a much better grasp on the rules lately, but in a session me and my party just had one of our party members (cleric) that my character was friendly with killed. Earlier in the session he'd taken his armor to a blacksmith to be upgraded, (he didn't have enough money to purchase the whole thing so we all pitched in a little) before it was complete he was killed by a monster, so after we'd defeated the beast and were about to leave town I returned to the blacksmith to collect the armor. He informed me he'd only give it to the cleric, I told him the cleric was dead, so he said "Awh what a shame, you can buy it off me." Naturally this somewhat frustrated my character and they got into an argument which resulted in the blacksmiths death. Afterwards guards appeared and arrested my character, outside of my cell the party discussed whether or not they should break me out, with many of them voting not to and only one voting to do it. As such my character was left to die in the cell, he broke out himself later but my question is this, Is it reasonable to assume that my character would hold a grudge against the ones who in is eyes betrayed him? He's chaotic neutral if that helps. (Side note, ooc I don't hold any grudges and don't care that they chose to do that, I just think it could create an interesting dynamic, sort of like in Telltale games)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The question seems to be *Is it reasonable for my character to hold a grudge?* and I don't think that's a question the site can answer—for you or your character. (The site won't answer alignment questions anyway—too contentious—, so that's not a factor.) If you're looking for a place to *discuss* options or role-playing, try [these forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610). Also, considering the events, you may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/8610). Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Once you have enough rep(20) - you may consider joining our [chat] to discuss roleplay and character motivations.

Comment: I just want to say that I love the line "Naturally this somewhat frustrated my character and they got into an argument which resulted in the blacksmiths death."  So casual.  So quaint.

Comment: @gilhad See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: OK, my bad. You are right. Reading that FAQ just now.

Comment: While your question is currently not fit for our site. There are answers that might be interesting reads, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105682/34130 is an example of someone in a similar situation.